# Beginner Python issue: test_func has no definition?

Tags: python

I'm just having an issue with a small beginner project in learning Python. I'm trying to call a 'test_func' from a class with no luck, calling it from another file informs me that this class has no such module where obviously trying to call it directly in the class tells me it hasn't been defined.

On Sublime I've tried ensuring that all indentation has been changed from tabs to spaces but I'm still getting this error. I must have made a stupid mistake somewhere (I'm assuming I've made a mistake or two on the init method but I was hoping to sort that once I've sorted this) I'm just hoping someone can point it out for me? Thanks!

```
import Card

cardCount = 0
suitCount = 0

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):

        self.deck = []

        while suitCount <= 4:
            while cardCount <= 13:
                self.deck.add(Card(cardCount,suitCount))
                cardCount += 1
                continue
            suitCount += 1
            continue

    def read_deck(self):
        for card in self.deck:
            print(str(card))
    def test_func(self):
        print('Printing test func')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_func()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test_func() belongs to the class deck and is not defined outside that context. So in order to call that function you would need to create an instance of Deck():

```
deck = Deck()
deck.test_func()
```

If you want to access it without first creating an instance of your class you can do it directly with `Deck.test_func()`. Alternatively you can also look at the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorators and read up on that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can call using the class

```
Deck().test_func()
```